# Aqueous copper and how it reacts with NH3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

I have learnt that you can test whether an unknown metal is copper by doing a simple test tube reaction. The reaction involves adding aqueous $\ce{NH3}$ to the test tube which contains the copper.

The $\ce{NH3}$ as it is dissolved in water will form $\ce{NH4+}$ ions and $\ce{OH-}$ ions. The $\ce{OH-}$ ions react with the copper forming a precipitate $\ce{([Cu(H2O)4(OH)2])}$ but many other metals form a precipitate with $\ce{NH3}$ as well such as $\ce{Fe^2+}$, $\ce{Fe^3+}$ etc. So to make sure that it is copper present in the test tube you add an excess of $\ce{NH3}$ as this causes a ligand exchange reaction to occur producing $\ce{[Cu(H2O)2(NH3)4]2+}$.

Why doesn't this occur with the other metals? Why doesn't this occur for say $\ce{Fe^2+}$ to form $\ce{[Fe(H2O)2(NH3)4]2+}$ which would also be soluble?

Comment: I think the formation of a blue precipitate is already an evidence that the metal is copper. Further addition of ammonia should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

[Fe(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>6</sub>]<sup>2+</sup> is a high-spin d<sup>6</sup> complex, while [Fe(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>2</sub>(NH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>4</sub>]<sup>2+</sup> is a low-spin d<sup>6</sup> complex. The ligand substitution reaction is not favourable in terms of spin, so aqueous Fe<sup>2+</sup> does not react with excess ammonia.

However, both [Cu(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>6</sub>]<sup>2+</sup> and [Cu(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>2</sub>(NH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>4</sub>]<sup>2+</sup> are d<sup>9</sup> complexes. Their spins are the same, and being a stronger field ligand, NH<sub>3</sub> increases the crystal field stabilization energy, so ligand substitution is favourable.